# How to push the data from Azure Data Lake to SSAS ( Azure analysis Service) ? Is it possible?

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services

Azure data lake is my data source. I want to push data from azure data lake to Azure Analysis Service (SSAS). How i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supported. In following documentation of Azure Analysis Services, Azure Data Lake is not listed in Data Source providers list:

https://opbuildstorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/output-pdf-files/en-us/Azure.azure-documents/live/analysis-services.pdf

Comment: Can we use HIVE ODBC Drive at lease we connect HIVE table

Answer (score 0):

This is supported.

You need to use a compatibility level of 1400. I have the latest Azure Data Lake plugin for VS2015. You would need to add Data Lake Store as a data source.

There is a good series of blogs here which give you insight of building azure analysis service on top of BLOB storage. The same principle can be applied to data lake store as well:

- Part 01 :
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/05/15/building-an-azure-analysis-services-model-on-top-of-azure-blob-storage-part-1/
- Part 02 :
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/05/30/building-an-azure-analysis-services-model-on-top-of-azure-blob-storage-part-2/
- Part 03 :
  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/06/22/building-an-azure-analysis-services-model-on-top-of-azure-blob-storage-part-3/

---

### Update

This blog goes in details how to do this. the basic premise is the same as the blob storage backed SSAS process. They however introduced a data lake store connector.

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/09/05/using-azure-analysis-services-on-top-of-azure-data-lake-storage/

[image]